# Is it possible to start Windows 8 with the touchscreen disabled (intentionally)?

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen

Scenario: touchscreen damaged, so once Windows is loaded it clicks around and there is no way to do anything.

I was wondering if there a way to load Windows with the touchscreen disabled on purpose?  Some boot time flags maybe?

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this error with mine I solved it by removing the device from Device Manager to effectively disable the hardware. I found no way of disabling touch functionality using Windows methods of any kind (e.g., control panel, admin tools, etc.). At that time I couldn't find anything more on Google either.

If the clicking is happening too much it may be hard to do things so it is possible that booting into safe mode would disable the touch screen and allow you to remove the appropriate input device.